# Update Password using SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am developing an application using SQLite. My requirement is that I want to update a password in my table.

I wrote an update query but it is not working. Error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "' WHERE username = ?": , 
while compiling: UPDATE TABLE_USER SET password = god' WHERE username = ?` condition.
```

The code:

**UserDaoImpl.java**

```
public void  updateEntry(String newPassword,String name)
 {
    Cursor cur= myDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+UserDBHandler.USER_TABLE+" SET    
 "+UserDBHandler.PASSWORD+" = "+newPassword+"' WHERE "+ 
                   UserDBHandler.USER_NAME+" = ?",new String[]{name});  
 }       

  ChangePasswordActivity.java


public class ChngePasswordActivity extends Activity {

  private EditText oldPwdEdit;
  private EditText newPwdEdit;
  private EditText cnfrmEdit;

  private Button submitBtn;

  private String oldPwd;
  private String newPwd;
  private String cnfrmPwd;

  private UserDaoImpl userDetalsIml;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_changepassword);

    //Bundle extra = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    //String name= extra.getString("udp");
    Intent intent2=getIntent();
    final String name1=intent2.getStringExtra("val");
    Log.e("prasad2",name1);

    oldPwdEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.oldEdt);
    newPwdEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newpswEdt);
    cnfrmEdit  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pswEdt);  

    submitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cnfrmPwdBtn);

   submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            oldPwd = oldPwdEdit.getText().toString().trim();
            newPwd = newPwdEdit.getText().toString().trim();
            cnfrmPwd=cnfrmEdit.getText().toString().trim();

            if(oldPwd==null||"".equalsIgnoreCase(oldPwd)){
                String header = "OLD PASSWORD REQUIRE";

                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),header,100).show();
            }
            else if(newPwd==null ||"".equalsIgnoreCase(newPwd)){
                String header = "NEW PASSWORD IS REQUIRE";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), header,   
                                   100).show();
            }
            else if(cnfrmPwd==null ||"".equalsIgnoreCase(cnfrmPwd)){
                String header = "COINFIRM PASSWORD IS REQUIRE";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), header, 
                                   100).show();
            }
            else if(!newPwd.equalsIgnoreCase(cnfrmPwd)){
                String header = "PASSWORD DOES NOT MATCH";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), header,   
                                   100).show();
            }
            else{

                userDetalsIml = new   
   UserDaoImpl(getApplicationContext());

                userDetalsIml.updateEntry(newPwd,name1);


            }       

        }
    });  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `'` in your query at here UserDBHandler.PASSWORD+**" = "**

Try this updated one

```
Cursor cur= myDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+UserDBHandler.USER_TABLE+" SET    
 "+UserDBHandler.PASSWORD+" = '"+newPassword+"' WHERE "+ 
                   UserDBHandler.USER_NAME+" = ?",new String[]{name});
```

Comment: Yes dude your right. I vote up your answer. I have also posted this.

Comment: thank you but my update data do not effect on database ,it show previous data onlu

Answer (score 4):

Ooops!! you have done a very little mistakes.

Please replece your code

```
Cursor cur= myDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+UserDBHandler.USER_TABLE+" SET    
 "+UserDBHandler.PASSWORD+" = "+newPassword+"' WHERE "+ 
                   UserDBHandler.USER_NAME+" = ?",new String[]{name});
```

by

```
 Cursor cur= myDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+UserDBHandler.USER_TABLE+" SET    
 "+UserDBHandler.PASSWORD+" = '"+newPassword+"' WHERE "+ 
                   UserDBHandler.USER_NAME+" = ?",new String[]{name});
```

There is only missing `'` before newPassword .

Comment: thank you it changing but in database does not change data i took any mistake

Comment: means update data do not effect on database, it still keeps the previous data?

Comment: Is "USER_NAME" in your database table is primary key? are you sure about this?

Comment: please do this , because primary key is very much necessary to identify a particular row values or particular user. I have a good database structure. but how I will give this ? because here your question is different.

Comment: ya I gave Primary key also but does not work. i gave like this                   String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
    + USER_TABLE+ " (" + USER_NAME+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + " VARCHAR," + PASSWORD + " VARCHAR,"
    + CONFIRM_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR," + USER_MOBILE_NUMBER + " VARCHAR"
     + ")";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44751/discussion-between-user3081942-and-satyaki-mukherjee)

Comment: Oho please look your code " + USER_NAME+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " . you have taken USER_NAME as integer, but when you have updated this then you have given String ? how it's possible?

Comment: ya i changed integer to string but it does not work please help me

Comment: no please keep this as Integer and then in update process send the user id as integer . You database structure is in wrong way.